# Ignore lazy vals while saving into couchdb using sohva

Tags: scala, couchdb, lift, lift-json

We're using [sohva](https://github.com/gnieh/sohva) in project.

It uses lift-json to serialize the model case classes to persist into CouchDB.

We have lazy vals in these models which we don't want them get persisted.

Is there a way to tell lift-json to ignore these attributes?

Comment: Post your question at the [Lift community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb) for the best response.